# "rails generate model" hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ROR.

How can I use the same App name after I delete my rails App?

Following are the actions I performed. Step #6  is my problem.

1 - Environment

```
 - OS : Ubuntu 12.04.4
 - ruby : 2.1.1p76
 - rails : 4.1.2
 - DB : SQLite
```

2 - Create rails App :

```
rails new myApp
=> OK
```

3 - Create model :

```
 rails generate model mytable name:string
=> OK.
```

4 - Delete rails App :

```
 rm -rf myApp
=> OK
```

5 - Re-Create rails App :

```
 rails new myApp
 => OK
```

6 - Re-Create model :

```
 rails generate model mytable name:string
=> Not OK! waiting for infinite time
```

Comment: which query browser you are using? you can remove your database from there as well. and also try `rake db:drop:all`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just a hunch, but by any chance, are you still running a server process somewhere on your machine?  That could be holding a lock that is preventing the new table from getting built.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it was spring server causing this. `kill -s 15 SPRING_SERVER_PID` helped.

Comment: I had to use `ps aux | grep spring` to get this PID. Had been up for 267 hours ;)

Answer (score 5):

Don't kill spring, just use the built in `spring stop`

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps

1 - Create rails App :

```
 rails new myApp
```

2 - Create model :

```
 rails generate model mytable name:string
```

3 - Drop The database :

```
 rake db:drop
```

4 - Delete rails App :

```
 rm -rf myApp
```

5 - Re-Create rails App :

```
 rails new myApp
```

6 - Recreate Database

```
 rake db:create
```

7 - Re-Create model :

```
 rails generate model mytable name:string
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your database still has the table corresponding to your model from the first time you created it. What database system are you using? Performing `rm -rf` does not generally affect the database since the data lives outside the Rails app directory. You may need to reset the database with

```
$ rake db:reset
```

This will delete the table that was left over from the first time you created the model.

Note: If you are using SQLite for your database, this may point to a different problem.

Comment: I'm using SQLite. DB was deleted when running 'rm -rf'